Why is $\int_{1}^{z} \left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{a}{z^3}\right)\cos(z) \,dz$ Single-Valued iff Residue of Integrand, at $z=0$, is $0$?
The following is a question from an old complex analysis qualifying exam:
For what value of $a$ is the function $\int_{1}^{z} \left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{a}{z^3}\right)\cos(z) \,dz$ single-valued?
The provided solution states: The function $F(z) = \left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{a}{z^3}\right)\cos(z)$ is analytic in $\{z: 0< |z| < + \infty\}$, and its Laurent expansion around $z=0$ is
$F(z) = \left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{a}{z^3}\right)\cos(z) = \left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{a}{z^3}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{2!}z^2+\frac{1}{4!}z^4-\cdots \right) = \frac{a}{z^3}+\left(1-\frac{a}{2} \right)\frac{1}{z}+\left(\frac{a}{4!}-\frac{1}{2} \right)z+\cdots$
The necessary and sufficient condition for $f(z)$ to be single-valued is that the residue of $F(z)$ at $z=0$ is zero. Hence we obtain $a=2$.
My question is the following: why is the residue of $F(z),$ at $z=0,$ being zero a necessary and sufficient condition for $f(z)$ to be single-valued?

Think about what happens when you integrate $\frac{1}{z}$ vs when you integrate any other power of $z$

Hint: go from $1$ to $z$ along two different paths such that going from $1$ to $z$ along one, and then back from $z$ to $1$ along the other, you wind around $0$, and then apply the residue theorem

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb C$ be a simply connected domain, let $a\in\Omega$, and let $f:\Omega\setminus\{a\}\to\mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function. Consider the integral
$$\int_w^zf(\zeta)\,\mathrm d\zeta,$$
where $w,z\in\Omega\setminus\{a\}$ with $z\neq w$. We claim that the value of this integral is independent of the path taken from $w$ to $z$ in $\Omega\setminus\{a\}$ if and only if $\mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{\zeta=a}f(\zeta)=0$.
Take two simple rectifiable curves $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$, both starting at $w$ and ending at $z$. Let $\gamma$ be the rectifiable Jordan curve obtained by joining the two curves, traversed anticlockwise. If the interior of $\gamma$ (i.e. the region it encloses) does not contain $a$, then $f$ integrates to $0$ over $\gamma$ by Cauchy's integral theorem, and so consequently the integral along the curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are the same. Suppose now that $a$ lies in the interior of $\gamma$. Then by the Residue theorem we have that
$$\int_{\gamma_1}f(\zeta)\,\mathrm d\zeta-\int_{\gamma_2}f(\zeta)\,\mathrm d\zeta=\pm\int_{\gamma}f(\zeta)\,\mathrm d\zeta=\pm2\pi i\mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{\zeta=a}f(\zeta),$$
where the $\pm$ is determined by the orientation of $\gamma$. As $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ were arbitrary it then follows that
$$\int_{\gamma_1}f(\zeta)\,\mathrm d\zeta=\int_{\gamma_2}f(\zeta)\,\mathrm d\zeta$$
for all simple rectifiable curves $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ in $\Omega\setminus\{a\}$ from $w$ to $z$ if and only if $\mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{\zeta=a}f(\zeta)=0$. This is precisely what we wanted to show, as the original integral is defined by integrating along some path from $w$ to $z$, so we have shown that this takes one unique value independent of the path if and only if $f$ has zero residue at $a$.
